# how can we validate duplicate in database table while inserting data from excel

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, oracle

I have created a sql table which contains 38 columns and I am importing data from excel to sql table for inserting I have used bulkcopy option while importing once data is imported and while we insert again data is inserted again duplicates are coming so please give me the solution for validate and insert

Comment: Has this table unique key? How do you insert data? With which tool? The question is too broad.

Comment: insert data from excel to data table am using asp.net c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the same thing for my project. I have many files but with different names and all files have different data. So I used filename as unique ID and inserted the filename as a value in a new column in Table. Before uploading I check if the same filename is listed in Table or not. Look for something unique in your excel files, may be name, or anything you see is unique.